# how do I list all teams owned by a user

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Is it possible (with powershell) to list all the teams groups where one person is owner of?
For example user A is owner of several Teams (that i know).
How do i list this up in Powershell?
I would want a list of all teams groups where one of the owners is that specific user A.

I tried figuring it out but can't...
Tried for a loop to check all groupids but i can only list members of output every teams with their owners... I only wish to see the teams where user A is one of the owners

thanks : )

Comment: You can follow below article to get the all the groups the user is owner or member of.  https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1655/quickly-list-all-groups-a-user-is-member-of-or-owner-of-in-office-365